# How to get values from array in strings.xml in order of each day?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to get values ​​from an array every day, respectively, and set these values ​​to a textbox. I can get values ​​from array and set them in textbox but next day value stays same. does not set the next value in array? what can I do?

```
<string-array name="morning">
    <item>Good Morning. Message 1.</item>
    <item>Good Morning. Message 2.</item>
    <item>Good Morning. Message 3.</item>
</string-array>
```

```
mTestArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.morning);

preference_shared = this.getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE);
text_shared = this.getSharedPreferences("TEXT", MODE_PRIVATE);

Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int timeOfDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);

if (timeOfDay >= 0 && timeOfDay < 24) {
    if (preference_shared.getBoolean("isFirstRun", true)) {
        dailyGreetings.setText(mTestArray[(0) % (mTestArray.length)]);
        saveDate();
    }else {
        if (!Objects.equals(preference_shared.getString("Date", ""), dateFormat.format(date))) {
            int idx = new Random().nextInt(mTestArray.length);
            dailyGreetings.setText(mTestArray[idx]);
            text_shared.edit().putString("TEXT", dailyGreetings.getText().toString()).apply();
            saveDate();
        }
        else {
            dailyGreetings.setText(text_shared.getString("TEXT", ""));
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Your if block will never run unless today is within the range of 1 - 23 of Jan. `timeOfDay` will return 325 for Nov 21.

Comment: Adding log can help you to identify the problem more easily. (i.e., `Log.d($ActivityTag, "$method: timeOfDay=" + timeOfDay);`)

Comment: @AndroidNewbieA what can ı do for this situation?

Comment: Assuming that you want to get the time in 24 hour clock,
you shall call `c.get(HOUR_OF_DAY)` to retrieve it.

Comment: And in case you want to know the details, just give a Google search and find the trusted site. (i.e., https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#HOUR_OF_DAY)

Answer (score 0):

It's Easy just

```
Resources res = getResources();
String[] mornings = res.getStringArray(R.array.morning);

//then use mornings  as you use array.
```

Comment: I already used it like this in the above lines. unfortunately it didn't work.  it still takes the first value in the array.  When it happens the next day, it doesn't get the other value.  It shows the value of the first day.

Answer (score 0):

```
String morning[] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.morning);
```

Comment: welcome bro. if its help you then please vote it.

Comment: I already used it like this in the above lines. unfortunately it didn't work.  it still takes the first value in the array.  When it happens the next day, it doesn't get the other value.  It shows the value of the first day.

Answer (score 0):

```
    // Solution
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("my_preference", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    String currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy", Locale.getDefault()).format(System.currentTimeMillis());
    String[] msgArrays = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.morning);

    String savedDate = sharedPreferences.getString(DATE_KEY, "");
    int savedCounter = sharedPreferences.getInt(COUNTER_KEY, 0);


    // First time
    if (savedDate.isEmpty()) {
        editor.putInt(COUNTER_KEY, savedCounter);
        editor.putString(DATE_KEY, currentDate);
        editor.apply();
    } else if (!savedDate.equals(currentDate)) {
        // New date appears, update shared preference.
        savedCounter++;
        if (savedCounter < msgArrays.length) {
            editor.putInt(COUNTER_KEY, savedCounter);
            editor.putString(DATE_KEY, currentDate);
            editor.apply();
        }
    }
    binding.tvTitle.setText(msgArrays[savedCounter]);
```

In this snipped of code, I'm updating shared preference by date and counter.

**Date:** It will be saved for next date, and if these both are not matching, shared preference will gets update with counter.

**Counter:** The position of your strings-arrays.

**Reset:** I have add another check that if in case your counter reaches to the end of array, it will be reset to **'0'**.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply dear  @Sohaib Ahmed. I will try when I go to home.

Comment: binding in the last line confused me? No binding code above. Where is the beginning of the binding code?

Comment: You can ignore that, just set your text to any textview, like
findViewById(R.id.textView).setText(msgArrays[savedCounter]);

Comment: thank you for your reply. it is work for me. alright how can show another activity msgArrays[savedCounter]. you made this with sharedpreferences.

Comment: Just get the value of counter from SharedPreferences and get your string using same array.

Comment: My Pleasure. Thanks for finding my answer helpful